# Make UI Responsive by Converting database calls to async calls in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, asynchronous, win-universal-app

I am using the new [Data Access in Universal Windows Platform](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/03/data-access-in-universal-windows-platform-uwp-apps/). I am able to retrieve data but the problem is since the retrieval code is synchronous in nature, the windows app becomes unresponsive till the complete list is retrieved. Since its Binded to an `ObservableCollection`, UI updates as soon as list is retrieved.

```
public List<Brand> retrieveBrands()
{
    List<Brand> brandList = new List<Brand>();
    using (var db = new CarDataContext())
    {
        brandList = db.Brands.ToList();
    }
    return brandList;
}
```

But now since there is a time lag between retrieval of list so UI becomes unresponsive for few seconds.
How can I make this retrieval asynchronous/make my method async so that as soon as list is retrieved I am able to get a task.Completed notification and UI is remains responsive.

My question is almost similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18046204/2898399) but since there is no answer I am posting a question.

Comment: Have you tried to retrieve your data in another thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
public Task<List<Brand>> retrieveBrands()
{
    return Task.Run(()=>
    {
        List<Brand> brandList = new List<Brand>();
        sing (var db = new CarDataContext())
        {
            brandList = db.Brands.ToList();
        }
        return brandList;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes thats what I was planning on doing. But there's a concept of `Asynchronous all the way` does this method helps us in achieving that?

Comment: @Jerin you can try adding async and await keywords. It should work

Comment: @LovetoCode what do you think of the implication on my app if I create these threadpool. Is it really async all the way? Is this the only way was hoping to find a different method than `Task.Run` when I posted the question.